# Data loading speed issue in full calendar

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, sql-server, fullcalendar

Am facing this loading issue in my Javascript based asp.net c# full calendar. Actually it loads and show the results very slowly if there is huge previous data for any specific account. If the data is comparatively less in another account, then it loads drastically faster. 
Any help for resolving this issue would be much appreciated.
Thanks a lot!!

Database: Microsoft SQL Server 2014, Technology stack: ASP.net 4.0, C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to limit the data to a certain window by using the start and end provided in the events function by fullCalendar:

```
, events: function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
            fetchEvents(start, end, timezone, callback);
        }
```

And then limit the data window to e.g. 4 months (2 months in the future, two months in the past) in the function itself:

```
// make a large window of data in order to avoid missing long-events on the calendar - they won't load otherwise
start.subtract(2, 'months');
end.add(2, 'months');

start = start.format("YYYY-MM-DD") + "T" + start.format("HH:mm:ss");
end = end.format("YYYY-MM-DD") + "T" + end.format("HH:mm:ss");
```

Finally, use the start and end in your call. I'm using Sharepoint API so part of my REST API query URL looks like this, but it can be different depending on your data source:

```
"and StartDate ge datetime'" + start + "' " + /* start of events window */
"and EndDate le datetime'" + end + "'" + /* end of events window */
```

Obviously that would mean you need to limit the max length of your events.

Comment: Please can you provide some sort of reference as i am new for full calendar